# Turn a secret key (using AES) to a string

Tags: string, base64, secret-key

Just a quick question:

how can i convert a SecretKey to a string?

Using javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter for base64 i get the following error message:

printBase64Binary(byte[]) in javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter cannot be applied to (javax.crypto.SecretKey)
                    String myAesKey_as_string = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(myAesKey);

The code is :

```
        KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES"); 
        SecretKey myAesKey = keygenerator.generateKey(); 
        String myAesKey_as_string = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(myAesKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates printBase64Binary expects a byte array as an argument but you are passing an object implementing the SecretKey interface instead. 
Try

```
DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(myAesKey.getEncoded ());
```